# Can I write sampleVideoView? = findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.videoView) in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The following code is from a Kotlin sample project, I think I can always write `sampleVideoView? = findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.videoView)`,  right?

**And more**

The code  `sampleVideoView?.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(HLS_STREAMING_SAMPLE))` is equivalence with `if (sampleVideoView!=null){sampleVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(HLS_STREAMING_SAMPLE))}` ,right?

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

        private var sampleVideoView: VideoView? = null

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            sampleVideoView = findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.videoView)
            sampleVideoView?.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(HLS_STREAMING_SAMPLE))
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> sampleVideoView? = findViewById(R.id.videoView)

This is no valid syntax. The `?` is used to mark types as nullable and for safely accessing variables holding these nullable types.

> The code sampleVideoView?.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(HLS_STREAMING_SAMPLE)) is equivalence with if (sampleVideoView!=null){sampleVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(HLS_STREAMING_SAMPLE))} ,right?

True. But if you have for example `val x = y?.getName()` variable `x` will be `null` or contain the name of `y` afterwards. It's not just "do only if `!= null`" as your example could suggest.

Comment: Thanks! but I can write  private var sampleVideoView: VideoView? = null, why can't I write sampleVideoView? = findViewById(R.id.videoView)

Comment: Because `VideoView?` is the type of your variable `sampleVideoView`, here `?` is valid and indicated that the variable can be ``null``, but you can't suffix a variable name with`?`, there's simply no syntax for that. Just do `sampleVideoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView)`

Answer (score 2):

You can forget findView method at all and replace it with kotlin android extension plugin

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

after that you can write just :

`yourVideoViewID.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(HLS_STREAMING_SAMPLE))`

Answer (score 0):

The below is correct syntax for assigning a nullable value to a nullable variable. You do not need a question mark at the assignment

```
 sampleVideoView = findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.videoView)
```

The second statement is an equivalence